# can't use foreach right in csh

Tags: arrays, shell, foreach, csh

I am kinda new to c shell and it seems I can't use a `foreach` loop for something that returns an array.

I get an error message citing `missing }`and I know the problem is in this following line:

```
foreach line ( `grep if "$f"`)
```

Here's the full code:

```
set f = $<
echo $f
if (-f $f) then
    echo $f
    foreach line (  ` grep if "$f" ` )
        echo ${line}
        if (${line[0-]}=~/(\d)+/) then
            echo "wow ${line} is an amazing arithmetic condition"
        endif
    end
endif
```

Comment: get a simpler version of your `foreach` to work first. I really don't think that `line` would tolerate spaces, each of the space separated values would be a new element in the array (not a whole line).  And, unless your job is mandating you to use csh, .... run away! ksh and bash are so much better. Put another way, paste the value of one line returned from `grep if $f` inside the `foreach line ( * paste grep return here* )` and see if that works. I bet it won't. Good luck.

Comment: ye i know bash is better but its mandatory at my work =[. it seems the problem is that the line i copy i get a line like this : if (blabla){ and the c shell thinks its a command or something...

Comment: consider editing this information into the body of your question, preferably with real data. Use 4 spaces at the front of a line to make it read as code. Good luck.

Comment: there is no way you are going to parse source code using only csh. I seriously doubt bash is a good tool for this job either. Can you explain better why you need to do such high level programming with a shell script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add more quotes to prevent interpreting of various special characters, for example:

```
echo "$line"
```

In general, you always want to quote all variables unless you have a reason not to do so.

In addition, `=~` doesn't do what you expect it to do. From `csh(1)`:

> The operators `=~` and `!~` are like `!=` and `==`  except  that the  right  hand  side  is  a  glob-pattern (see Filename substitution) against which the left hand operand is matched.

It's a basic glob pattern and *not* a regular expression!

There is no way to do regexps in (t)csh. A pattern like `/(\d)+/` doesn't work anywhere in csh. We'll need to rely on external tools such as `grep`, we can actually use our previous `grep` invocation to combine both `if` statements. A full example:

```
set f = "$<"
echo "Using file: $f"

if ( -f "$f" ) then
    foreach line ( "`grep -P 'if.*?\d' "$f"`" )
        echo "wow $line is an amazing arithmetic condition"
    end
endif
```

Gives me:

```
$ echo in | csh a.csh 
Using file: in
wow if (42 > 666) { is an amazing arithmetic condition
```

When used with the input:

```
$x = 'foo';

if ($foo) {
    print('bar');
}

if (42 > 666) {
    print('FizzBuzz!');
}
```

Also note that I added `"` quotes surrounding the backticks in the `grep` command − you can find out why by reading the documentation for `foreach` in `csh(1)` ;-)

Comment: This reads more like a "here is how to make your program work" rather than an answer to the OPs question, which is simply asking for an explanation of the error. After reading this answer several times I still don't know what was causing the error.